# React-router browserHistory.push doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Trying to use `browserHistory.push` method to change my route programmatically.

It will change the route (per browser address bar) but doesn't update the view.

Here's my code
  App.jsx

```
const AppStart = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path="experiences" component={Experiences} />
            <Route path="people" component={Profiles} />
            <Route path="login" component={Login} />
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppStart />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Component:

```
handleLoginRedirect(e) {
    browserHistory.push('/experiences');
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1'>
          <form role='form'>
           <RaisedButton label="Redirect" onClick={this.handleLoginRedirect} />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Actually just figured it out, can't believe it. I didn't see that I used hashHistory instead of browserHistory inside <Router>, changing to browserHistory fixed everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your router configuration uses `hashHistory` while you're pushing onto `browserHistory`.

It's easy to miss something like this and it's understandable.

- Replace `hashHistory` with `browserHistory` in your `Router` like so:

`<Router history={browserHistory}>`

Full Snippet:

```
const AppStart = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path="experiences" component={Experiences} />
            <Route path="people" component={Profiles} />
            <Route path="login" component={Login} />
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep, that was the issue, thank you, figured it out almost as soon as I posted here, after a couple of hours debugging :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the newest react-router api you'll need to use:

```
this.props.history.push('/path/goes/here');
```

You may need to bind ***this*** to your function when accessing *this.props* (note: ***may***):

```
onClick={this.handleLoginRedirect.bind(this)}
```

Please refer to the following question for all the information on this topic:

[Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: When you say latest, what version did you mean? AFAIK, browserHistory.push is supported and here's a usage example in react-router docs: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#navigating-inside-deeply-nested-components. HTH